# Прозрачная кнопка на Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Помогите сделать кнопку прозрачной как указано на рис.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто drawable в backrground установите

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Создайте новый **xml** файл в **res/drawable** и после добавьте свойство **background** c именем созданного файла.

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#1e2826" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#8a16806b"
        android:endColor="#b515ab78"
        android:startColor="#383838" />
</shape>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:text="Sign up" >
```

Comment: Обновил ответ. Сделал кнопку более похожей на ту что вы показали.